# Is rest mass determined by the kinetic energy of inner particles?

Tags: special-relativity, mass

I haven't studied physics in many years, please forgive my lack of proper formalism. With that being said...

The total energy is a function of rest mass energy and the velocity of the object, and is the equivalent of relativistic mass in Special Relativity. But what generates rest mass? Isn't it the kinetic energy of the inner movement of particles, down to the electrons' spin, that all objects have?

Since the faster it goes, the heavier an object becomes, movement, kinetic energy, generates (is?) mass. Then isn't it that "rest" mass is simply generated by inner movement? If all the atoms and electrons that constitute an object would somehow stop, wouldn't the rest mass suddenly become 0, making the object basically dissapear?

So is mass simply movement?

Comment: Electrons are point particles, with no internal structure or "inner movement", according to all measurements done so far. Despite this, electrons have a nonzero rest mass.

Comment: Almost the same question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413664/relativistic-mass-of-components-gives-system-rest-mass, and I have comments a lot of valuable links therein